# How could I optimize this query that currently uses RLIKE with word boundaries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I do a search on my site, I want to search three columns for the search phrase.  Because I don't want a search for "John" to return "Johnson", I currently use RLIKE with word boundaries.  However, my table has over 400,000 rows and this query is very slow.  Can anyone think of a faster way to do the same thing?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (
         (accountholder RLIKE '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]') 
      OR (alternatename RLIKE '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]')
      OR (payeename RLIKE '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]')
);
```

Comment: Just an idea but not tested so I won't post it as an answer: would "WHERE (concat(accountholder,alternatename,payeename) RLIKE '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]')" do the trick?
All I know is that you might try not indexing any of the accountholder,alternatename,payeename if you use concat because it could decrease performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for a whole word, much better solution would be to use FULLTEXT index. So, your table has to be MyISAM (if it isn't, create one table you will using just for searching and make a relation between that one and your table)...then, create FULLTEXT index on the columns you are searching, and make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (accountholder, alternatename, payeename)
AGAINST ('+John' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

...that will really boost your performance.

You can find a good start [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).